# Why can't I call a union of functions with a union of parameters?

Tags: typescript

I expect `arg` to be an union but it turns out to be an intersection.

```
interface Foo { a: string }
interface Bar { b: string }
type Func<T> = (arg: T) => void;
function foo(func: Func<Foo> | Func<Bar>, arg: Foo | Bar) {
  func(arg); // error!
  // Argument of type 'Foo | Bar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo & Bar'.
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce error using this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAWgjFAvFA3gKClAhgLigCjACcB7MAZz3U0wGMqMbMATOPYIgVwkcwF9GfAJRIAfFABuJAJbNGAIzwByAF5wlaAWlCRYAJiSpGuAsTKUjTepaZRmevOQ7SAdgHNeUAfxGJxU2QVlFT0NLVoSFycoAA9DfGpsABooeU08eCgAH31fcUTpADMCeSREZFV1EUTMLATPOgZbGlZ2Lh5m7xphQU0gA)

Comment: Definitely strange!
It is erroring for me in Visual Studio Code. Do you know if there might be anything in my setup causing this?

Comment: Support for [control flow analysis in destructured discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) was just introduced in TS4.6 which was released a few days ago.  Upgrade to TS4.6 and this will start to work.

Comment: Before TS4.6, having `a` and `b` as separate variables means the compiler considers them to be independent of each other, and thus checking `b` has no implication on the type of `a` (as if you didn't check `b`). You can't call `((x: X)=>void) | ((y: Y)=>void)` with `X` or `Y`; the only safe thing to pass in is `X` *and* `Y` at the same time (`X & Y`).  See docs for [calling unions of functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)

Comment: So what do you want to see here in terms of an answer? You've asked a few questions, which have different answers (why intersection? why not union? how can I make it a union?) and you've got an essentially false premise: there's no way that `c` should be a *union* of both types, because that wouldn't be type safe. Not sure which of these is the main issue, not to mention the "upgrade to TS4.6" aspect.  Could you please narrow down the post to ask a single, well-defined question?

Comment: Thanks, upgrading to TS4.6 seems to have solved this. I think I started this question not understanding the problem as you pointed out correctly. So while I got my problem solved, I'm not sure how to turn this into a better question for other people who may come across this.

Comment: Maybe the question could be "why can't I call a union of functions with a union of parameters" and give an example that doesn't have the "checking" aspect to it.  Like [this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/WKVEzm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler's behavior here is intentional and preserves type safety.  Before TypeScript 3.3 you couldn't even call a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of functions unless the parameter types were identical.  TypeScript 3.3 introduced [improved behavior for calling union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) and made it possible to call a union of functions with an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of parameters.  It would be unsafe to allow such a call with a union of functions.  From your example:

```
interface Foo { a: string }
interface Bar { b: string }
type Func<T> = (arg: T) => void;

function baz(func: Func<Foo> | Func<Bar>, arg: Foo | Bar) {
  func(arg); // error!
}
```

Let's imagine that the above code had no error in `func(arg)`.  Let's see what happens with particular `func` and `arg` values:

```
const func: Func<Foo> | Func<Bar> =
  Math.random() < 0.01 ?
    (arg: Foo) => console.log(arg.a.toUpperCase()) :
    (arg: Bar) => console.log(arg.b.toUpperCase());

const unionArg: Foo | Bar = Math.random() < 0.99 ?
  { a: "hello" } :
  { b: "goodbye" }

func(unionArg); // imagine no compiler error
// very likely runtime error like arg.b is undefined
// (occasionally HELLO or GOODBYE)
```

Here, `func` is a `Func<Foo> | Func<Bar>`.  There is a 1% chance it will be a `Func<Foo>` and a 99% chance it will be a `Func<Bar>`, and we don't know which.  And `unionArg` is a `Foo | Bar`.  There is a 99% chance it will be a `Foo`, and a 1% chance it will be a `Bar`.  If there were no compiler error in `func(unionArg)`, you'd happily assume that everything is fine.

But of course, at runtime, there is about a 98% chance that you are calling a `Func<Bar>` with a `Foo` input and a runtime error of the form `arg.b is undefined` will occur.  Oops.

---

The problem here is that a union of functions is more restrictive than either function type separately.  It's only safe to pass in a `Foo` to a `Func<Foo>`, and it's only safe to pass in a `Bar` to a `Func<Bar>`.  And if you don't know if your function is a `Func<Foo>` or a `Func<Bar>`, the only safe thing you could possibly pass in would have to be *both* a `Foo` *and* a `Bar`.  That is, `Foo & Bar`, the intersection:

```
const intersectionArg: Foo & Bar = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye" }
func(intersectionArg) // probably GOODBYE, occasionally HELLO, never runtime error
```

The `intersectionArg` is both a `Foo` and a `Bar` because it has both a `string`-valued `a` property and a string-valued `b` property.  Calling `func(intersectionArg)` is always safe, because no matter which function body ends up being executed, the parameter will definitely have the expected property.

---

Hence the intentional and useful conversion from a union-of-functions to an intersection-of-parameters.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7LgLmQGcwpQBzZAXwChRJZEUAhOKHZAI0JLJEtpgAngAcUqAK4gEAHgAqAPmQBeZAAo25QnICUKpQDd0wACYBuGjCkIwwdCC5wAXmqvTCk6TIzolAHzRrGVYoBQAaPCgtNExkAJC9bBpkZDcEDSidM2QAehzkaCh0KABCZNz8gEEoiQBbCHBkdBhkYTFkAHIfOOQQjuRgImQQdDA8IiJgchA4TgAbFDAsETY4eoYmlraULtiAMl62DoA6GloaBHsSVOsPIJ9-QK8QpWVygFk4MAALY6g4EAmdC1NR6GTIAAMxwhAEZkAB+copDLRHx6ZRKS4gIjoBbHObocgo45wY5LACqIjEUAAwnAiBBQXp8Ej1JpCAl9MgsTi8QSiZpjpwyehKdS6QymRYLlcxlI7CBqqjYvE2CpkJ8fn8AUCQWDIccAJyGhHlXAEZAAIm+EDmBMt1GQLJSuG4VvImBMnCEEAd51IQhw5TSanl9iVWQqyAM0EDc2AAGtbYGoFJbPUClAilAIugEAh6Qq4HbAwBxADy5YAIswAJoAUSa7AAEvWADJt8tnblfBDfdQQRLlHm4iD4wlqQdRyLkIUDIZSEwQGCgCAmM40GXYsb0aAMmwKpUefaHdiqc2Ea22+0RN2Wj3oL0+v2WaxqXdQfe2cOZKMiIqcLMcxlpWNYNrm+aFvYxbAcgrYduWEQgBAMbsKm4DABmhTFEAA)